# Is this question really still off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Post: [What are the options for creating a SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) RefactorLog file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47149185/64279)

I understand now that asking where to find a spec is considered off-topic after I received a close-vote, but I reworded my question to describe the actual problem as the guidelines suggest and it still got closed.

The original question was where to find a spec so that I can generate a refactorlog file. The new question was how to generate a refactorlog file. How is that still off-topic?

Comment: The post looks Too Broad now, still not an appropriate question.

Comment: Ask yourself: Do you think your question can be answered in a few paragraphs without being a link to an off-site resource?

Comment: @BDL, absolutely. A refactorlog file is not complex. It's just an XML file with a few options. I just don't know what those options are or what combo of options are valid.

Comment: The xml schema you linked and for which you state "appears to list the possible elements used in the refactor log" shows 100+ elements. Or maybe I missunderstand what you actually want.

Comment: @BDL, I only ever see one of those elements actually used in a refactorlog file. I'm guessing multiple features/components unrelated to the refactorlog share the rest of the XSD.

Answer (score 9):

The phrase

> but I'm looking for a complete list of options and a description of which combination of options are valid.

makes it sound like they're asking for a fairly broad list of things, or an enumeration of things.  That's enough to make it "too broad".

Comment: I just edited the question again. Is it any better now?

Comment: @adam0101: It's not leaving me with a lot of warm and fuzzies, honestly.  It's still asking for a reproduction of a list which sounds like it'd be something that you'd get from the official documentation.

Comment: I'm not sure that there is any official documentation.